# Jade in Express JS is not Rendering

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am excepting a username from a from with input(name="name").

The name is coming as i have checked with console.log(res.body.name). Even res.send("message") is working but the jade is not working.

My index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/', function(req, res){
    var user = req.body.name; 
    if(user) {
            console.log('User Exist');
            res.render('show_message', {message: "User exist", type: "UserExist"});
        }
    else {
            console.log('User is New');
            res.render('show_message', {message: "User Doesn't exist", type: "NoUserExist"});
      }

}

module.exports = router;
```

show_message.jade

```
html
head
    title Person
body
    if(type=="LoginSuccess")
        h3(style="color:green") #{message}

    if(type=="error")
        h3(style="color:red") #{message}

    if(type == "success")
        h3 New person, name: #{person.name}, Registered

    if(type == "NoUserExist")
        h3(style="color:red") #{Message}

    if(type == "UserExist")
            h3(style="color:red") #{Message}
```

The jade is not rendering. A blank webpage is coming.

Answer (score 0):

Variable are case sensitive - `{message}` instead `{Message}`:

```
if(type == "NoUserExist")
    h3(style="color:red") #{message}

if(type == "UserExist")
        h3(style="color:red") #{message}
```

Comment: Thanks Stdob. It was really helpfull.